# How can I make the thickness of an opencv line bi-directional in python?

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, image-masking

I'm trying to mask off the face of a person from a frame in the video, and i have the outline of the jaw as a set of 17 coordinates (from ibugs). I overlaid a line outlining the jaw using the function cv2.line, but it appears that the line only grows thicker in one direction, not the other.

```
thick = 20
for i in range(0,16):
    mask = cv2.line(mask,(int(landmarks[i][0]),int(landmarks[i][1])),(int(landmarks[i+1][0]),int(landmarks[i+1][1])),
                    (255,255,255), thick, 4)
mask = cv2.line(mask, (int(landmarks[16][0]), int(landmarks[16][1])), (int(landmarks[0][0]), int(landmarks[16][1])), 
                (255,255,255), thick)
mask = cv2.line(mask, (int(landmarks[0][0]), int(landmarks[0][1])), (int(landmarks[0][0]), int(landmarks[16][1])), 
                (255,255,255), thick)
```

an image of thickness 20

[image: an image of thickness 20]

an image of thickness 50

[image: an image of thickness 50]

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Update: worked properly once jupyter notebook was restarted, not sure why